# Decrypting a json string using java cryto package resulting in wrong json string

Tags: java, encryption

I have a Json String

```
            String message = "{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"rccCubeType\":\"TCR_CASE_D\",\"timeZone\":\"Asia/Kolkata\",\"timeOffset\":\"+05:30\",\"tenant\":\"0001\",\"extractionTime\":\"20170713162718117\"}";
```

I am encrypting this string using

```
 import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
 import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
 import javax.crypto.*;
 import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
 import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
 import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
 import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
 import java.lang.reflect.Field;
 import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
 import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
 import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
 import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
 import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
 import java.security.spec.InvalidParameterSpecException;
 import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

 public class AESEncrypter {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AESEncrypter.class);
private static final byte[] SALT = {
    (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32,
    (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03
};
private static final int ITERATION_COUNT = 65536;
private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 256;
private Cipher ecipher;
private Cipher dcipher;

public AESEncrypter(String passPhrase)  {
    SecretKeyFactory factory = null;
    Field field = null;
    try {
        // hack for JCE unlimited strength policy jar installations
        field = Class.forName("javax.crypto.JceSecurity").getDeclaredField("isRestricted");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

        field.set(null, false);


        factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), SALT, ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);

        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] iv = ecipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Invalid Key Exception",e);
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Invalid Algorithm Parameter Exception",e);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        LOGGER.error("No Such Padding Exception",e);
    } catch (InvalidParameterSpecException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Invalid Parameter Exception",e);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Invalid Key Spec Exception",e);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        LOGGER.error("No Such field Exception",e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Class Not Found Exception",e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Illegal Argument Exception",e);
    }


}

public String encrypt(String encrypt) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
    byte[] encrypted = new byte[0];
    try {
        bytes = encrypt.getBytes("UTF-8");
        encrypted = encrypt(bytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception",e);
    }
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
}

private byte[] encrypt(byte[] plain)  {
    try {
        return ecipher.doFinal(plain);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Illegal Block Size Exception",e);
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Bad Padding Exception",e);
    }
    return null;
}

public String decrypt(String encrypt) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] decrypted = decrypt(bytes);
        return new String(decrypted);
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrypt)  {
    try {
        return dcipher.doFinal(encrypt);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Illegal Block Size Exception",e);
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Bad Padding Exception",e);
    }
    return null;
}




public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String password = "F1C0T0N83LL34";
        String message = "{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"rccCubeType\":\"TCR_CASE_D\",\"timeZone\":\"Asia/Kolkata\",\"timeOffset\":\"+05:30\",\"tenant\":\"0001\",\"extractionTime\":\"20170713162718117\"}";
        AESEncrypter encrypter = new AESEncrypter(password);
        String cipher = encrypter.encrypt(message);
        System.out.println(cipher);
        System.out.println(new String(encrypter.decrypt("I8YbMaRvAw+rzPQu//uXnDDFrk/EtscXpcxBzqonVOpJ1VjvpwtRGwrsEz9R1rroC95Vj9bzPDbkX2qdLXK4jLKlzaoINXOxF+dHslnBVl3xG61qh9QdCuMTBzEEw18K51JJu+13bjuUO20+0uZiY5q6Wg1sQ60C0QEeO/7K9F/TSUN1r5l02Q9NSDQJpkvlglHZEfPJ7ST4179oqlQUjQ==").getBytes("UTF-8")));
     }
 }
```

I am decrypting the encrypted string using dcipher object, but when i copy the value of the encrypted string and do a dcipher of the copied string i get some junk values like

```
e_N���<�E=>�,"rccCubeType":"TCR_CASE_D","timeZone":"Asia/Kolkata","timeOffset":"+05:30","tenant":"0001","extractionTime":"20170713162718117"}
```

where am i going wrong? when i process these things in memory that is within a single run, the decryption is going through correctly.

EDIT 1: adding the complete class

Comment: I think the problem is with the secret. on single run while encrypting and decrypting .. same secret is used. when you copy the encrypted code and try to decode you need the same secret through which you have encrypted earlier

Comment: It works for me. You are not showing the code that is actually giving you the problem.

Comment: Do you use the same AESEncrypter instance to decrypt as to encrypt?

Comment: @bowmore Yes i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the **IV** used when encrypting the string. Here you just initialise an encrypt cipher and takes the random **IV** it generates - this won't work, it needs to be the one used when you actually did the encrypt.

You need to come up with a scheme for handling the **IV** when encrypting, so you have it when you need to decrypt. An often used method is to prefix the encrypted message with the **IV**. So it's readily available when you need to decrypt. It don't need to be secret.

Comment: No, he does extract the IV used for the encryption and sets it on the decryption cipher in his example.

Comment: He don't encrypt with it .. he just initialises a cipher and takes the iv.

Comment: A messed up header of an encrypted string is a classic messed up IV.

Comment: the ecipher instance generated a random IV automatically, then he extracts it and uses it to initialize the dcipher instance.

Comment: i didn't understand how prefixing the iv to the secret message works

Comment: After encrypt you have an iv that needs to be passed along with the encrypted data. You can pass this along as a separate piece of data, or you can just add it in front of the encrypted data like Base64(<iv> + <encrypted data>) .. this way you only need to pass one piece of data around. You need to split it again before decryption of cause .. The IV have a fixed length, so it's easy to split again ..